# iOS library to detect app stats

Tags: iphone, ios, statistics

Is there any iOS library which detects various user stats within the app like time spent on a view, number of times app was activated etc.? Any suggestions will be most welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the google analytics sdk [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/)
or localytics sdk [here](http://www.localytics.com)

Answer (score 2):

1. There is an open source project on github:
   https://github.com/Countly/countly-sdk-ios
2. There are many stats SDKs based on web server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any native library, there are allot of simple API's to do this. You could however, if you wanted to do it yourself, use some of app delegates methods to log statistics to a plist. But that isn't really the best option. Honestly, Google Analytics on a blank UIWebView page would be an effective and easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Flurry* analytics sdk here to  detects various user stats

```
**www.flurry.com**
```